# The meaning of "what"?

Tags: semantics, pronouns, pragmatics, interrogatives

"What" is defined grammatically as an interrogative pronoun

> ... used interrogatively in asking for the specification of an identity, quantity, quality, etc. (Wiktionary)

In dictionaries, however, *what* is never defined semantically.

If I meditate on a word like *car*, I inevitably associate images, feelings and experience with the word. Even if I think of *nothingness* I somehow associate sensations and a mental image of emptiness (even if it may be wrong). When I contemplate the word *who*, I associate the word with a "person whose identity is unknown". When I think of *what* however, in terms of pragmatics, it seems to suggest a request for more information to the interlocutor, but semantically, I cannot find any meaning to it.

Hence this odd question:

What is the semantic meaning of *what* (or its equivalent in any language)? Could the meaning of *what* be defined as "a thing unknown to me"?

Comment: What do you mean by 'semantic' (and maybe also 'pragmatic')? Sure, you can't point at it. It has lots of semantics, but mostly as a place-holder, a variable, more grammatical function (-in- the language rather than in the world).

Comment: In the sentence "what is your name?" the verb "to be" suggests *your name = what*. *What* relates to *that* as a pronoun and its semantic is abstract, standing for some entity the interlocutor and I both know. Yet at the same time *what* denies the premise of a pronoun, because it expresses the absence of knowledge about *that*. Can it be said then that *what* means *that which is unknown to me*? In which case it would be an pragmatic request for more information.

Comment: If its function would be merely grammatical, i.e. turning a sentence into an interrogative, why does it require the verb "to be"? Would the sentence not simply be "what your name?", then? See example in response to Mark, where Hindi uses *kyā* in both ways.

Comment: I don't see the difficulty. Sure, 'what' means something unknown. Why does requiring a verb cause a problem? Do you expect 'What are you called?' really to be 'What you?' ? Is the problem 'synsemantic'? (if so then all verbs are a problem for you). You say "what is never defined semantically". I don't agree; I find the dictionary definition semantic. What's your idea of 'semantic'?

Comment: By semantic I understand the association of a word with its meaning as opposed to its grammatical function. In dictionaries, "what" is defined as an interrogative pronoun, not with a meaning like "cup". In view of this lack I am questioning whether "that which is unknown to me" may be a possible semantic definition for *what*. I am trying to say that perhaps the grammatical function of the word, i.e. suggesting interrogation, is overloading its semantic and that the request for more information is merely pragmatical.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by 'semantic'. My conception of it includes the definition of 'what'. What is the semantics of any purely grammatical function word? It has them, they're just not so comparable to those you get for nouns or verbs. You say "I cannot find any meaning to it", what do you mean by 'meaning"? Do you need a referent? A sensation? What's the meaning of 'two'? or 'idea'? or 'among'? or 'you'? or 'not'? They all have meaning/semantics, just not as obvious as 'apple' or 'running'.

Comment: @Mitch: `They all have meaning/semantics, just not as obvious as 'apple' or 'running'.` Well this is precisely the point of my question :) Yes, I am talking about the referent: whether concrete, abstract, tangible or intangible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2248/discussion-between-mitch-and-benjamin)

Comment: In the same vein as "who," perhaps "An object or concept the nature of which is unknown to me."

Comment: "person, whose identity is unknown" is "somebody", not "who".

Answer (score 7):

I'd say that "what", like other [interrogatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word), is generally a [function word](http://strazny.com/encyclopedia/sample-function-words.html) -- synsemantic -- and has little to no intrinsic lexical meaning. Its meaning is always determined by context. So, the semantic meaning you're looking for probably isn't there!

Comment: I thought that too, on the other hand though, if the common sentence were "What your name?" I'd think *what* purely is synsemantic, turning the sentence into an interrogative. But sentences are "What **is** your name?" suggesting *what* **is** something. See my point?

Comment: For instance in Hindi, the equivalent of *what*, *kyā*, can be used in two ways: 1. as with English *tumhārā nām kyā hai?* (*what's your name?*) and 2. purely synsemantic *kya tumhārā nām John hai?" (*is your name John?*). In the second case, the interrogative pronoun is functioning as a pronoun, it merely indicates the sentence is a question as with Spanish *¿*.

Comment: Some function words are deictic, that is their meaning is determined by context. Also, you made a wrong assumption about "What is your name." I speak several languages where the verb to be is absent/not required in that sentence. Not all words of natural language have clearly defined referents. There are  words which underwent grammaticalization, that is they almost lost their lexical meaning and now they merely express some grammatical concept.

Comment: @AlexB. I understand that *what* is understood as a grammatical concept. Is it necessary the lexical meaning of the word has completely subsided in the process of grammaticalisation? In the Hindi example I provided, there is a clear distinction between a purely grammatical function and the lexical meaning of the same word. PS: In the language you mention, is the use of *what* adjectival then?

Comment: _What_ is a **variable**, like the _X_ in an equation; it can mean anything that isn't an individual human (which would require _who_), depending on who's saying it to whom in what sentence in which context. It has no fixed meaning, just a set of parameters (non-human) and a set of usages (pseudo-cleft constructions, wh-question constructions, etc.). It's not that it has no meaning, it's that it doesn't have much, and what it means in a given context isn't likely to be the same in a different context.

Comment: @Benjamin It may be helpful to consider that in English (many other languages) the interrogative and relative pronouns have identical forms. Informally -- in a sentence like "_Who_ is the person _who_ did that?" both _who_ 's have the same unknown referent but different contextual 'meanings'. Its function determines its meaning from the context.

Comment: @jlawler: explaining *what* as a variable makes much sense. You should put this as an answer. I also have some comments on it.

Answer (score 3):

After all the comments above, there's not much left to say. I didn't really want to post it as an answer but the quotes from Bhat 2004 (since you wanted references) are too long for a comment.

"Interrogative proforms are used primarily for **obtaining information** from the addressee **regarding an unknown entity**, and hence the speaker can provide only a general indication of its identity. He is therefore forced to use a general term for referring to it. Even when interrogative pronouns have some of their extended uses like testing the knowledge of the addressee, there would still be a need to use a general term."

and

"Proforms [...] are general terms that are used for carrying out different functions like (i) identifying the participants of an event by locating them with reference to the spatio-temporal location of the speech act participants (or indicating the location, time, manner, etc. of the event itself in a similar fashion), (ii) referring back (or forward) to other expressions that occur in the utterance or in previous utterances, or (iii) indicating the scope of a question, negation, or exclamation. They are generally made up of two different elements of which one indicates the function of the preform (demonstrative, interrogative,
indefinite, or anaphoric (relative) ) and the other one denotes their category or
scope (person, thing, place, manner, quality, quantity, etc.)."

"**All proforms** share a set of general concepts and hence **expressing a general concept** can be regarded as the first set of their main functions."